# How should I send viewmodel to Create method in Controller?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am trying to send data from a view to a controller Create method. But the view model parameter is getting null values when the create method is called.

In my view I want to add a item and show a list of added items.
I have tried to send data to the create method but its view model parameter is getting null values.

In the following code whenever Create method is hit the value of p.posts and p.post is null. How can I get the value of p.post  and p.posts here?

Controller method

```
public ActionResult Create(PostsViewModel p) {}
```

View Model

```
public class PostsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Post> posts;
    public Post post;

}
```

View

```
@model NotesWebApplication.ViewModels.PostsViewModel
```

...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())  {
```

...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.post.postText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

...

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Also in my Create method if I wanted to add Bind then which should be added

```
[Bind(Include="postText")]
```

or

```
[Bind(Include="post.postText")]
```

**update**

I made the following changes in PostsViewModel class

```
public class PostsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Post> posts { get; set; }
        public Post post { get; set; }

    }
```

and the Create method in the controller is changed to

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="post, posts")]PostsViewModel p) {}
```

This is what the httpget Create method looks like

```
// GET: Posts/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            PostsViewModel postsViewModel = new PostsViewModel();
            postsViewModel.posts = db.Posts;
            postsViewModel.post = new Post();
            return View(postsViewModel);
        }
```

Now when I submit the form p.post in the controller parameter receives the desired value. But p.posts remains null. Why is this hapenning?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is u don`t have an instance of your post object. Try to make your viewModel something like this:

```
public class PostsViewModel
{
    public string PostText {get;set;} // don`t forget to make it like property, not just a field
}
```

and then create an instance in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(PostsViewModel p) 
{
   Post post = new Post{ postText = p.PostText};
   //and do what you want with it
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the value of p.post in the Create method parameter PostsViewModel p . But I am still getting p.posts as null .

Comment: You don`t use it at all, do you? What is your play exactly?) Your array of posts gotta be in somewhere like dbcontext, if i got you right

Comment: Can I not get the proper value of p.posts in the parameter ? Yes the values can be obtained from dbContext. I am only wanting to know why is the value in the parameter null.

Comment: You don`t create any object. You got value from that post, but your inctance is still anonymous, so you getting null.:D You can try to make your post property in viewmodel as virtual. That`s gonna help you to not get null

Comment: using virtual with the posts property is still giving the same result.